# One big single redis instance for everything or multiple redis instances?

Tags: node.js, express, redis, socket.io, message-queue

I have an expressJs server that manages many things including **user sessions, message queues, caching data and socket.io all of this using redis**. So my question is:

- Would it be better to use one redis instance for each purpose ( 1
  redis for user sessions, 1 redis for message queues, 1 redis for data caching, 1 redis to manage socket.io sessions etc) ?
- Or is it better to use one single redis with prefixes ?

In both methods, what are the pros and cons ? (CPU, RAM consumption etc).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your setup, how much data you're storing, how often you do read/write, what the TTL for  each cache  and what the cost of all that look like.

However, generally I would suggest starting simply with one Redis instance until you see a need for having a more complex setup.

Comment: Have you tried the single redis instance approach ? since redis is a key-value store would it be a good idea to store everything there ? like cached data, session data, etc using prefixes ?

Comment: As long as you namespace your data correctly, make sure that each service queries the data with proper name-spacing i don't see any major issue. If your redis data is not persisted, be prepared that all your cache to be dropped though. This may be ok for some cached data, but could be more annoying where you're dealing with sessions. 

It is all about tradeoffs for your particular usecase

Comment: Note that some things have to be configured at a server level e.g. eviction policy, so I'd think about that, but broadly agree starting out with one and then expanding is a good way to go.

Comment: Also note that with a single instance, unless you use a cluster, your dataset size will be limited to the size of RAM available to redis-server on the one machine.  This may or may not be an issue, and if it becomes one then one way you could mitigate it would be by using multiple Redis instances for different roles in your application e.g. cache in one, durable data in another.